# Inner Join php para procurar em duas tabelas

Tags: php, inner-join

Preciso fazer a busca com o PHP dos dados digitados em duas tabelas MySQL, `produtos` e `usuario`.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
$array = array(); 

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM produtos inner JOIN usuario ON produtos.nome = usuario.nome
    WHERE produtos.nome LIKE '%{$query}%'");

     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $array[] = $row['nome'];
     }
     echo json_encode($array);
```

Mas não retorna nada na busca, como poderia resolver isso?

Estrutura do banco:

```
produtos
id | nome

usuario
id_usuario | nome
```

Tentei com o `UNION` como fui instruído aqui mas também não deu:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT nome FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%{$query}%' limit 5 UNION Select usuario FROM nome WHERE nome LIKE '%{$query}%' limit 5");

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row['nome'];
 }
 echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Qual é a chave estrangeira que faz a relação entre as tabelas?

Comment: chave estrangeira no MySQL tipo InnoDB

Comment: Você precisa "fazer a busca em duas tabelas" ou precisa "buscar conforme a relação entre elas"? As duas tabelas não parecem ter relação, mas mesmo assim você fez um JOIN. O JOIN serve para tratar do relacionamento entre tabelas, não para unificar e fazer a busca.

Comment: De onde vem o valor de `$query` em `LIKE '%{$query}%'` para definir a variável `$query`? Isso está errado, não está!?

Comment: teria que ser com o UNION? como ficaria?

Comment: tentei com o UNION mas também não funcionou

Comment: Mas qual o resultado que espera obter? Todos os produtos cujo nome seja exatamente igual ao nome do usuário? Se for então use INNER JOIN, se não for então explique o que deseja.

Comment: Você tem que ter um campo na tabela de usuários/clientes que os relacione a tabela produto/mercadoria, por exemplo um campo `usuário.compra` cujo o valor é um `produtos.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> produtos.nome = usuario.nome

Seu join está pegando registros cujo nome do usuário é igual ao nome do produto.

No `join`, use os campos que estão relacionados, que não sei quais são pois não sei como está a estrutura dessas tabelas.

Comment: coloquei a estrutura no banco na pergunta

Comment: Tenho que pegar os registros digitados no formulario usei o WHERE produtos.nome LIKE '%{$query}%' nao seria isso?

Comment: Você tem um valor e precisa consultar se ele existe na tabela de produtos e também ver se existe na tabela de usuários?

Comment: isso usei o UNION mas não consegui

Comment: Se esse é o caso, você precisa de um `union` não de um `join`. No union que vc postou está `Select usuario FROM nome`....está invertido o campo e a tabela